# Nest mapping the same type twice

Tags: elasticsearch, .net-core, nest

I'm in trouble with Nest. I have a brand new index on Elasticsearch 5.1.1 and I'm trying to define a type mapping by dotnet core.

My classes look like that:

```
public class Review
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public bool HasSpoiler { get; set; }
    public bool BoughtInIngresso { get; set; }
    public ReviewStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public class User
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }


public class Movie
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

In my application, I'm trying to define a short form of the type mapping (just for test) like that:

var pool = new StaticConnectionPool(nodes);

```
    var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool);
    settings.DefaultIndex(elasticSettings.IndexName);

    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

    client.Map<Review>(m => 
        m.Index("my_index")
        .Type("reviews")
        .Properties(ps=>
            ps.Keyword(k=>
                    k.Name("title"))
            .Text(t=>
                    t.Name("comment"))
        )
    );
```

And the final result is this. Observe the reviews AND review mapping being created. I only want "reviews", not "review".

```
{
  "my_index": {
    "mappings": {
      "reviews": {
        "properties": {
          "comment": {
            "type": "text"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "keyword"
          }
        }
      },
      "review": {
        "properties": {
          "boughtInSite": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "comment": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "date": {
            "type": "date"
          },
          "grade": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "hasSpoiler": {
            "type": "boolean"
          },
          "id": {
            "type": "text",
            "fields": {
              "keyword": {
                "type": "keyword",
                "ignore_above": 256
              }
            }
          },
          "movie": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          "status": {
            "type": "long"
          },
          "title": {
            "type": "keyword"
          },
          "user": {
            "properties": {
              "id": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              },
              "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "fields": {
                  "keyword": {
                    "type": "keyword",
                    "ignore_above": 256
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I'm doing wrong? This happen if I use AutoMap() too. I don't want to map with attributes because I want to preserve my POCO classes, but if was the only way, I can do.

Some help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't shown how you are indexing `Review` types, but I suspect that you're not specifying the type as `"reviews"` when indexing; in this case, NEST will infer the type from the C# POCO type name.

NEST provides a way for the Elasticsearch type `"reviews"` to be associated with the C# POCO type `Review` using `InferMappingFor<T>()` on `ConnectionSettings`

```
public class Review
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
    public Movie Movie { get; set; }
    public int Grade { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Comment { get; set; }
    public bool HasSpoiler { get; set; }
    public bool BoughtInIngresso { get; set; }
    public ReviewStatus Status { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}

public enum ReviewStatus
{
    Good,
    Bad,
    NotTooShabby
}

public class User
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}


public class Movie
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

void Main()
{
    var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var defaultIndex = "default-index";
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
        .InferMappingFor<Review>(m => m
            .TypeName("reviews")
        )
        .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex);

    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);

    client.CreateIndex("my_index", c => c
        .Mappings(m => m
            .Map<Review>(mm => mm
                .Properties(ps => ps
                    .Keyword(k => k
                        .Name(n => n.Title)
                    )
                    .Text(t => t
                        .Name(n => n.Comment)
                    )
                )
            )   
        )
    );
}
```

With this approach, you don't need to specify the type on every request now, although you can override it per request if you need to.

[With `AutoMap()`, you can let NEST infer the Elasticsearch field types from the C# POCO property types](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/auto-map.html), [then use `.Properties()` to override any mappings you'd like.](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/fluent-mapping.html)